# Input in HTML5, checkbox gets unchecked

Tags: html, input

I have the following HTML5 code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Input</title>
</head> 

<body>
    <input type=text value="Enter your name" maxlength="10"> <br>
    <input type=checkbox checked>
</body>
</html>
```

Which is working fine, by the way. The checkbox as expected is checked. However, just after adding one line of code to introduce a password field, this following code makes the checkbox unchecked, even tough i have marked it "checked". This does not make any sense! Am i breaking any HTML5 rule?

The code after adding password field:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Input</title>
</head> 

<body>
    <input type=text value="Enter your name" maxlength="10"> <br>
    <input type=password> <br>
    <input type=checkbox checked>
</body>
</html>
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: always use quotes to surround the value of attributes & your `<head>` is incomplete. Also, form elements should be surrounded by `<form>` tag. Last, form element should have `name` attribute. Fix these HTML problems before proceed.

Comment: In which browser doesn't this work?

Comment: It works actually. I am not sure which browser you are using. Confirmed in Firefox and Chrome. I had checked the code first and the checkbox was unchecked, then I posted as answer after closing the br tags. But again it worked without closing the <br> tags. Wierd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is correct actually ..working on Chrome, firefox mozilla and IE

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Input</title>
</head> 

<body>
<form>
    <input type=text value="Enter your name" maxlength="10"> <br>
    <input type=password> <br>
    <input type=checkbox checked>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```